How can I populate Textfield using php ajax in each row of a table upon change of another textfield within the row
I have a javascript where upon click of a button a row with two cells is added to the table. One cell has a livesearch textfield and the another cell has a quantity textfield, whose value suppose to dynamically change and/or determined upon click on the livesearch textfiled results.
I have tried somethin but the challenge I am facing is that the value of the dynamically determined textfield of other rows keep retainin the value of the first row textfiled.
So I am seeking for assistance on how to clean-up the script so that each row will respond according to its respective values in the livesearch textfield
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table id="stockTransfer" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="color:blue">Search Product's(Name/Code)</th>
        <th style="color:blue">instore Availability</th>
        <th style="color:blue">Price/Unit</th>
        <th style="color:blue">Choose Selling Unit(eg:cartons/etc)</th>
        <th style="color:blue">Quantity</th>
        <th style="color:blue">Cummulative Price</th>
        <th style="color:blue"> Delete </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script>
//stock transfer dynamic textboxes
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btnaddstockTransfer', function() {
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td><div class="search-box"><input id="stock" class="form-control is-warning stock" type="text" name="stock[]" placeholder="Search by name or code"><div class="result"></div></div></td>';
    html += '<td><input class="form-control is-warning eqty" type="text" name="stockeqty[]" readonly size="2"></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#stockTransfer').append(html);


    $(document).on('keyup input', '.search-box input[type="text"]', function() {
      /* Get input value on change */
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
      if (inputVal.length) {
        $.get("backend-search.php", {
          term: inputVal
        }).done(function(data) {
          // Display the returned data in browser
          resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
      } else {
        resultDropdown.empty();
      }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function() {

      var stock = $(this).text();

      $(this).parents(".search-box").find('.stock').val(stock);
      $(this).parent(".result").empty();

      var tr = $(this).parent(".search-box").parent().parent().parent();

      $.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: "saleqtyOnFly.php",
        data: {
          item: stock
        },
        success: function(data) {
          tr.find(".eqty").val(data);
        }
      })

    });
  });
});


Please format your code properly. It's pretty much illegible the way it is now.

Please have a look at How do I format my posts?, [ask], and how to make a [mre] of your issue. See also the [tour], since you haven't take it yet. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Having a $(document).ready inside another $(document).ready is completely redundant and pointless.

another text field in another td tag...this is vague. Be specific about exactly which field you are talking about and how we should identify it, then there is no ambiguity.

var stock = document.getElementsById('stock') will cause you a problem because it looks like you can have more than one <input id="stock" in your page. An ID must be unique. So JS will always only find and use the first item with that ID. All others are considered invalid. A few lines above that you already used $(this).parents(".search-box").find('.stock') to find a specific "stock" input by its position...so why didn't you do that again just below? It seems you didn't really think about that getElementById code carefully when you wrote it.

Also, putting event handlers inside other event handlers, as you've done, is a bad idea. You'll end up creating multiple handlers for each of those elements, which then will all fire whenever the event occurs. This generally creates unintended and confusing consequences. I'm guessing you did it that way because you don't know abut the "delegated event" handling pattern. Take a look at the "Direct and delegated event handlers" section in https://api.jquery.com/on/

@ADyson I have noted your suggestions I will work on it and get back if I experience any further challenge

@ADyson I have corrected the errors you noticed. Also for the var stock, I used this var stock = $(this).text(); instead of  var stock = document.getElementsById('stock'); However, I noticed that my quantity cell  tr.find(".eqty").val(data); for all previously inserted rows changes to the value of the quantity cell of the most recent row. At this juncture I need your help to hault this occurrance

for all previously inserted rows...this goes back to what I said about the fact you've put the $(document).on("click", ".result p", function() handler inside the $(document).on('click', '.btnaddstockTransfer', function() handler. Therefore every time the btnaddstockTransfer click event is triggered, it will add another event handler for .result p...and then another, and another. So eventually you will have 2 or more functions running for that event, and the previous ones may remember variable values passed to them from the context they had at the time they were first added.

Another reason could be because var tr = $(".search-box").parent().parent().parent(); will find all parent table rows of all search boxes, not just the search box near the clicked result. Probably you need $(this).parents(".search-box").parent().parent().parent(); instead.

@ADyson Yes, I tried using that but the cell was blank instead. That is to show var tr = $(this).parents(".search-box").parent().parent().parent(); was  not pointing to the cell. please we are almost there, help with another option

@ADyson Yes I have seperated the two click events

Can you edit the question with the latest code then, to show how you've done that and what the latest version looks like. That way we are both talking about the same thing. Also we don't have a sample of your overall HTML, so that makes it harder to work out what the correct jQuery should be, since we're guessing a bit about the structure.

The reason it's not populating your "quantity" textbox is because inside $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(), tr doesn't contain a jQuery object. That's because $(this).parent(".result").empty(); clears the "result" div, and that means $(this) no longer exists because that points to an element within the "result" div.
The simple solution is to assign tr before you clear the "result" div:
  $(this).parents(".search-box").find('.stock').val(stock);
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
  $(this).parent(".result").empty();

Here's a working demo (just using hard-coded sample data instead of the responses to your AJAX calls):


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btnaddstockTransfer', function() {
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td><div class="search-box"><input id="stock" class="form-control is-warning stock" type="text" name="stock[]" placeholder="Search by name or code"><div class="result"></div></div></td>';
    html += '<td><input class="form-control is-warning eqty" type="text" name="stockeqty[]" readonly size="2"></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#stockTransfer').append(html);


    $(document).on('keyup input', '.search-box input[type="text"]', function() {
      /* Get input value on change */
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
      if (inputVal.length) {
        //just dummy data for example purposes:
          resultDropdown.html("<p>Result 1</p><p>Result 2</p>");
        /*$.get("backend-search.php", {
          term: inputVal
        }).done(function(data) {
          // Display the returned data in browser
          resultDropdown.html(data);
        });*/
      } else {
        resultDropdown.empty();
      }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function() {

      var stock = $(this).text();

      $(this).parents(".search-box").find('.stock').val(stock);
      var tr = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
      $(this).parent(".result").empty();

      /*$.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: "saleqtyOnFly.php",
        data: {
          item: stock
        },
        success: function(data) {
          tr.find(".eqty").val(data);
        }
      })*/
      //just dummy data for example purposes:
      tr.find(".eqty").val(123);
    });
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnaddstockTransfer" type="button">
Add stock transfer
</button>
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table id="stockTransfer" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="color:blue">Search Product's(Name/Code)</th>
        <th style="color:blue">instore Availability</th>
        <th style="color:blue">Price/Unit</th>
        <th style="color:blue">Choose Selling Unit(eg:cartons/etc)</th>
        <th style="color:blue">Quantity</th>
        <th style="color:blue">Cummulative Price</th>
        <th style="color:blue"> Delete </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




Consider the following example.


//stock transfer dynamic textboxes
$(function() {

  function makeRow(table) {
    console.log("Add Row to " + $(table).attr("id"));
    var row = $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", table));
    $("thead th", table).each(function() {
      $("<td>").html("&nbsp;").appendTo(row);
    });
    $("td")
      .eq(0)
      .append($("<div>", {
        class: "search-box"
      }), $("<input>", {
        id: "stock-" + row.index(),
        class: "form-control is-warning stock",
        type: "text",
        name: "stock[]",
        placeholder: "Search by name or code"
      }), $("<div>", {
        class: "result"
      }));
    $("td")
      .eq(4)
      .append($("<input>", {
        class: "form-control is-warning eqty",
        type: "text",
        name: "stockeqty[]",
        size: "2",
        readonly: true
      }));
    return row;
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.btnaddstockTransfer', function() {
    makeRow($("#stockTransfer"));
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup input', '.search-box input[type="text"]', function() {
    /* Get input value on change */
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).closest("tr").find(".result");
    if (inputVal.length) {
      $.get("backend-search.php", {
        term: inputVal
      }).done(function(data) {
        // Display the returned data in browser
        resultDropdown.html(data);
      });
    } else {
      resultDropdown.empty();
    }
  });

  // Set search input value on click of result item
  $(document).on("click", ".result", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");

    $('.stock', row).val($(this).text().trim());
    $(this).html("");

    $.ajax({
      method: "get",
      url: "saleqtyOnFly.php",
      data: {
        item: stock
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $(".eqty", row).val(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
#stockTransfer thead th {
  color: blue;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnaddstockTransfer">Add Stock Transfer</button>
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table id="stockTransfer" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Search Product's(Name/Code)</th>
        <th>Instore Availability</th>
        <th>Price/Unit</th>
        <th>Choose Selling Unit(eg:cartons/etc)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Cummulative Price</th>
        <th>Delete </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



The fastest way to help clean things up is to take repeatable code and move it to a function.
It can also be helpful to use .closest() to find specific parent elements.
